# How do desktop browsers handle mobile meta tags?

Tags: html, mobile, browser, meta-tags

Specifically, would including `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>` in the header of a page that is served to both mobile and desktop browsers affect the layout when viewed in a desktop browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It will cause no problems with desktop browsers.