# Does Viewport affect desktop browsers?

Tags: html, mobile

### EDIT: Nevermind, found [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350225/how-do-desktop-browsers-handle-mobile-meta-tags) after searching for a completely unrelated topic (kinda serendipitous)

Probably a dumb question, but I have been unable to find a direct answer anywhere.

Does the viewport metatag (`<meta name="viewport" content="..." />`) have *any* effect on desktop browsers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do desktop browsers handle mobile meta tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350225/how-do-desktop-browsers-handle-mobile-meta-tags)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it doesn't. I suppose they could decide to interpret them, but it definitely won't be in the near future and/or interfere with your website.

Comment: I have a feeling that computer browsers may implement this in the near future. Once the screen density of computer monitors become just as varied as screen densities of phones, there will be a need to display your design at the same physical size across all monitors. Right now, the problem is not that severe, but I'm beginning to feel it. Some designs look too tiny on some of my monitors.

Answer (score 3):

No, they're ignored on the desktop. Mobile devices love them though.