# Change viewport-hardware pixel scaling

Tags: javascript, html, browser, screen, viewport

How do I make the pixels of the content of my browser (chrome 44.0.2403.155 m) coincide with those of my physical screen (laptop computer)?

I'm totally new to front-end development and just painfully discovered, after spending hours generating an image of a specific size in pixels, that the (virtual?) pixels in the browser's screen do no coincide with those of my physical screen hardware.
There's a lot of material out there about responsive design but there is not UX consideration to make in what I am doing.  What I need is the pixels in my browser to coincide with those of my screen.

I tried both
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1920">` (1920px is the width of my screen)
and
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
but I don't see any change, not even when I play with those numbers (Is this viewport meta tag intended only for mobile devices?).
I also learned that there exists the `window.screen` object and that `window.screen.height` and `window.screen.width` but they are read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a LOT of things I found the answer:
The reason why I didn't have a 1:1 scale between my browser's pixels and my physical screen's pixels was that my windows 10 was set to scale everything:

[image]

Taking this X% setting, the browser sets the width of its screen as

`(Physical Screen Width) / X%`

In my case, that is `1920px / 150% = 1280px`

After changing this setting to 100%, I get 1-to-1 correspondence between browser and screen pixels.

I also found here in StackOverflow that the viewport metatag does not affect a non-mobile (desktop, laptop, ...) device browser.  I would like I had found this answer in an official document, though.

[Does Viewport affect desktop browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333535/does-viewport-affect-desktop-browsers)

[How do desktop browsers handle mobile meta tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350225/how-do-desktop-browsers-handle-mobile-meta-tags)